Usage examples of How do you mean vs What do you mean?
I mostly understand the difference between How do you mean? and What do you mean? as explained by this answer
However, I was hoping to find some examples of their usage with context. Can someone give some examples of their usage in literature, where I can understand their difference clearly with context?

I would be entirely unsurprised to find "how do you mean" used where "what do you mean" makes more logical sense, at least in an informal context.

Illogically, What do you mean? is often used in the sense "Are you really saying that?"

What do you mean, you're not coming with me?

Of course, it can be a literal request to explain the meaning of a statement.
How do you mean? often means "In what sense are you using that expression?"

"Well, Richard, are you beginning to feel more settled now?"
..."How do you mean, settled?" returned Richard. (from Dickens: Bleak House)

